# If my top button on my iphone 4 doesn't work can I turn on my phone without connecting it to a charger?

Tags: iphone

I know that if your top button doesn't work and you turn off your phone then you can turn your phone back on by connecting it to a charger but is there a way to turn my phone on when the top button doesn't work without connecting my phone to a charger ?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do it. To make things easier,  you could turn on Assistive Touch, but it doesn't work when iPhone is turned off.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the only way to turn the phone on is by connecting it to a charger - I had exactly this problem with my iPhone 5. Assistive Touch works fine when the device is on but the only way to power on the phone is by plugging it in.